# attron(A_BLINK) using Ncurses does nothing

Tags: ncurses

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, gcc 4.8.2 and Ncurses 5.9.20140118; whenever I run any code like

```
attron(A_BLINK);
printw("Hi");
refresh();
```

the text that gets printed to the terminal doesn't blinks (or do hoola-hoops)- it's just regular text that would have been printed by

```
printw("Hi");
refresh();
```

I have tested it on xterm, default ubuntu terminal, gnome terminal and Guake with the same result. Do I need some special fonts with "Blink Support" or something for it?

Comment: You don't need special fonts. You _do_ need terminals that have support for blinking. However, checking the `terminfo` for xterm, at least, reveals that it does support blinking text. Are you using something like `tmux` or `screen` that would override your `terminfo`? Are you manually overriding `$TERM` in your shell? You can test your terminal for support by running the following in your shell: `echo "\x1b[5mtest"`. If "test" blinks, then you know your terminal supports blinking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your issue has to do with which terminal emulator you're using and what value the `$TERM` variable is set to. I was able to use some sample code I find that works with those 2 conditions were met, but it wouldn't work in same `gnome-terminal` or `terminator`.

#### [Sample code](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ncurses-does-not-blink-801444/)

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();

    attron(A_BOLD);
    addstr("Twinkle, twinkle little star\n");
    attron(A_BLINK);
    addstr("How I wonder what you are.\n");
    attroff(A_BOLD);
    addstr("Up above the world so high,\n");
    addstr("Like a diamond in the sky.\n");
    attrset(A_NORMAL);
    addstr("Twinkle, twinkle little star\n");
    addstr("How I wonder what you are.\n");
    refresh();

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it like so:

```
$ gcc -o blink blink.c -lncurses
```

You can see that it's working by piping its output to `hexdump`:

```
$ ./blink | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 3f 31 30 34 39 68  1b 5b 31 3b 33 31 72 1b  |.[?1049h.[1;31r.|
00000010  28 42 1b 5b 6d 1b 5b 34  6c 1b 5b 3f 37 68 1b 5b  |(B.[m.[4l.[?7h.[|
00000020  48 1b 5b 32 4a 1b 28 42  1b 5b 30 3b 31 6d 54 77  |H.[2J.(B.[0;1mTw|
00000030  69 6e 6b 6c 65 2c 20 74  77 69 6e 6b 6c 65 20 6c  |inkle, twinkle l|
00000040  69 74 74 6c 65 20 73 74  61 72 0d 0a 1b 28 42 1b  |ittle star...(B.|
00000050  5b 30 3b 31 3b 35 6d 48  6f 77 20 49 20 77 6f 6e  |[0;1;5mHow I won|
00000060  64 65 72 20 77 68 61 74  20 79 6f 75 20 61 72 65  |der what you are|
00000070  2e 0d 0a 1b 28 42 1b 5b  30 3b 35 6d 55 70 20 61  |....(B.[0;5mUp a|
00000080  62 6f 76 65 20 74 68 65  20 77 6f 72 6c 64 20 73  |bove the world s|
00000090  6f 20 68 69 67 68 2c 0d  0a 4c 69 6b 65 20 61 20  |o high,..Like a |
000000a0  64 69 61 6d 6f 6e 64 20  69 6e 20 74 68 65 20 73  |diamond in the s|
000000b0  6b 79 2e 0d 0a 1b 28 42  1b 5b 6d 54 77 69 6e 6b  |ky....(B.[mTwink|
000000c0  6c 65 2c 20 74 77 69 6e  6b 6c 65 20 6c 69 74 74  |le, twinkle litt|
000000d0  6c 65 20 73 74 61 72 0d  0a 48 6f 77 20 49 20 77  |le star..How I w|
000000e0  6f 6e 64 65 72 20 77 68  61 74 20 79 6f 75 20 61  |onder what you a|
000000f0  72 65 2e 0d 0a 1b 5b 33  31 3b 31 48 1b 5b 3f 31  |re....[31;1H.[?1|
00000100  30 34 39 6c 0d 1b 5b 3f  31 6c 1b 3e              |049l..[?1l.>|
0000010c
```

Switching to `xterm` with `$TERM` set to `vt100`. Here's a screenshot of the terminal.

[image: ss#1]

[image: ss#2]

Comment: @HalosGhost - thanks for the catch, I always do, I missed this one however 8-).

Comment: No one is perfect. :)

Comment: Modifying $TERM indeed made it work in xterm, it also worked in Konsole which makes me think I should switch to KDE. Thanks.

Comment: For the record, setting `$TERM` is not a solution. It's a workaround. Something is probably setting your `$TERM` incorrectly (overriding the `terminfo`). Fixing that is the actual solution.

Comment: @slm @HalosGhost Sorry to ping you guys on a very old post. I'm trying to resolve the same problem on MacOS with the default terminal, which has $TERM set to `xterm-256color` which I believe should support blinking. Like the OP, however, A_BLINK doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas on what I could be missing?

Comment: @mnoronha - ask it as a new question.

Comment: @slm Done. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353219/ncurses-attrona-blink-etc-do-nothing-in-mac-terminal if you're interested. Thanks for the pointer; wasn't sure if it was sufficiently different :)